# Short from 0600 to 0800, code is now shorting every second hour

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to backtest if a short is wise between 0600 and 0800 AM, but the code produces positions on every second hour : https://www.tradingview.com/x/rIyPT4tI/

I wonder if anyone has an idea of how to alter the code to only short at 0600 to 0800 ?

````
strategy("Backtest 1 hour", overlay = true)

timeFilter = (year >= 2018) and (month >= 7)

Longcondition = time("0600") and timeFilter
if (Longcondition)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, qty = 10)

Closecondition = timeFilter and time("0800")
if (Closecondition)
    strategy.close_all()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
strategy("Backtest 1 hour", overlay = true, process_orders_on_close=true)

timeFilter = (year >= 2018) and (month >= 7)

Longcondition = time("", "0600-0601") and timeFilter
if (Longcondition)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, qty = 10)

Closecondition = timeFilter and time("", "0800-0801")
if (Closecondition)
    strategy.close_all()
```

Comment: Aha, the devil is in the details! Thanks  :-)